# Update panel, postbacks and failed updates

Tags: c#, asp.net, updatepanel

I'm feeling very Seinfeldian here. What's the deal with UpdatePanels?

I've been reading posts, blogs and books for 2 days.

I have a JS Timer for testing purposes polls at 10 seconds. I want it to refresh the update panel. The update panel holds a literal. The update panel's on load re populates the literal. It doesn't work.

The javascript:

```
__doPostBack("<%=litL2Sched.ClientID %>");
```

This causes a full postback, my page blinks and then my eyes well up with tears of sadness.

```
__doPostBack("<%=btnL2Refresh.ClientID %>");
```

This does almost nothing. I was told this would work. When I click the button it works as expected, but will not come down with the timer.

Page Markup:

```
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="line2Sched" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional" OnLoad="litL2Sched_ResetTable"  >
        <ContentTemplate>

            <asp:Literal runat="server" ID="litL2Sched" ></asp:Literal>
            <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnL2Refresh" /> 
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

I've tried with and without triggers, my script manager allows partials.

All I really want to do is force a postback upon my lowly update panel.

EDIT:
Interval Code

```
var oUpdatePanels = setInterval(function () { postBacks() }, 10000);

function postBacks(){
    __doPostBack("<%=btnL2Refresh.ClientID %>", null);
}
```

I have some other stuff going on in there that tested that aren't affecting this. To clarify, I have 5 modules laid out like this, but I just want to get the one working and the optimize later after I understand.

Comment: try passing null as the second parameter of __doPostBack

Comment: Still does full postback. I should add I had that in there for a long time with "" as my 2nd param.

Comment: Have you tried it for the button? The Literal control doesn't have any events, so it shouldn't cause a postback anyway.

Comment: That makes sense, but the update panel does not refresh on the timer. As as side note earlier today when I was playing I had the button's visible property set to false and the postback escaped to the whole page.

Comment: See my updated answer. I as able to get it to work in a test website I created.

Comment: Rather than using a native JS timer and trying to call the postback yourself, why not just use an `ASP` timer in markup.  Even if you could get your method to work, it would be harder to work with and maintain for future developers than just a line in markup.

Comment: There is a ton of client side ops that happen for this page. It's monitoring a process for up time. I'm trying to limit calls back to the server. It's 10 seconds right now, but will likely be 10min in production. I could use an ASP timer, I need as much on the client as possible, but that's my constraint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass the ClientID of the UpdatePanel

```
window.setInterval(function() {
        __doPostBack("<%=line2Sched.ClientID%>", '');
    }, 3000);
```

**ASPX**:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="line2Sched" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional" OnLoad="litL2Sched_ResetTable" >
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:Literal runat="server" ID="litL2Sched" ></asp:Literal>
        <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnL2Refresh"/> 
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>

<script type="text/javascript">
function postBacks() {
    __doPostBack("<%=line2Sched.ClientID %>", null);
}

var oUpdatePanels = setInterval(postBacks, 1000);
</script>
```

Code Behind:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}

protected void litL2Sched_ResetTable(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    litL2Sched.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt");
}
```

**EDIT**

Your javascript needs to look like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function postBacks() {
        __doPostBack("<%=line2Sched.ClientID %>", null);
    }

    var oUpdatePanels = setInterval(postBacks, 1000);
</script>
```

Comment: `null` and `""` both postback the entire page.

Comment: Bah, full postback again. Curiously I went to the page source I'm getting the following: `<div id="MainContent_line2Sched">` as the updatePanel's translation and `__doPostBack("#MainContent_line2Sched", "");` as the translated javascript.

Comment: That's strange, I created an empty website with the code above and it's running perfectly. The time gets updated asynchronously. How are you determining that its doing a "full postback"?

Comment: An alert in `$(document).ready()` each time and the page blinks.

Comment: There must be something else going on somewhere else in your code. The above code is working just fine in a blank website. Can you post any additional code that might be relevant?

Comment: When I attached the `__doPostback()` to the update panel I kept the `#` in front like a jQuery selector. You had it right, I just had one of those stupid characters! Thank you for your patience and assistance! Thats what I get for copy and pasting.